# django 1.7 select a valid choice. 1 is not one of the available choices

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have this method:

```
def formset_ask_fill_choices(formset_ask, products): # products is a matrix
    for i, form in enumerate(formset_ask):
        products_i = products[i] # products_i is now a list
        CHOICES = []
        for product in products_i:
            CHOICES.append(product[0], product[1]) # product[0] is an int with the id and product[1] a string.
        form.fields['product'].choices = CHOICES
```

where the field `product` is set as:

```
    product = forms.ChoiceField()
```

when I use the formset in views, it shows me the right choices, however after I send the `POST` I get the error

> "select a valid choice. 1 is not one of the available choices".

Using a python shell I've checked that the method `formset_ask_fill_choices` produces a right `CHOICES` array.

Why am I getting this error if the choice is indeed in the `form.fields['product'].choices`?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that your `choices list` contains `same value for multiple names`, print the whole choices list on the terminal and see if the whole choice list has `distinct value` or not?

Comment: No, in my case CHOICES = [(1, "Spaghetti A"), (17, "Spaghetti B")]. The values will always be unique.

Comment: Did you print the `list` on the terminal or you are `assuming` this?

Comment: I did print it on the shell, several times! The output is the one I showed you!

Comment: It seems that a `ChoiceField` is not the proper approach for this problem.

Do you have a products model? Why not use a foreign key relationship and a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for this?

Also I’d recommend upgrading to Django 1.9